# what is CC compiler in Solaris 11 for compiling c programs. make file specifies something like " CC=cc -Xa -mt -xc99=no_lib"

Tags: c, gcc, solaris, cc

I have these lines in my make file:

```
ifeq ($(SYSTEM),SOLARIS)
    # SUN Solaris 8 no c99
    ifeq ($(OSVER),510)
        CC=c99 -Xa -mt 
        LD=c99
    else
        CC=cc -Xa -mt -xc99=no_lib
        LD=cc
```

I have to compile my code in Solaris 11. Previously someone compiled in Solaris 10 or 9. Not sure which.

If I execute `which CC` its giving "no CC in user/bin" error. But my Solaris 11 has GCC installed in it. Do I have change CC=GCC or I have install new CC. If i have to install new CC which one I have to install?

Comment: Executables are case sensitive, maybe `CC` doesn't exist, but `cc` does. What is the output of `which cc`?

Comment: Hi Tim  thanks for the response.which cc
which: no cc in (/usr/bin:/usr/sbin) this what i am getting.

Comment: @Tim The upper-case `CC` here is a `make` variable, that by convention is used to identify the C compiler to be used by the makefile. For example:  https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cc` typically points to the system default compiler.  On Solaris this would be part of SolarisStudio (which may or may not be installed).

If `cc` is not available (test with `which cc`), but `gcc` is, then your Makefile should be adjusted to point to the `gcc` location.

Your Makefile may now look like:

```
ifeq ($(SYSTEM),SOLARIS)
    # SUN Solaris 8 no c99
    ifeq ($(OSVER),510)
        CC=c99 -Xa -mt 
        LD=c99
    else ifeq ($(OSVER),11)
        CC:=/usr/sfw/bin/gcc
    else
        CC=cc -Xa -mt -xc99=no_lib
        LD=cc
```

Comment: Thanks.If cc is not installed, and if I want to install what version I have to install.Where can I get that?

Comment: Try following the thread [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12731/usr-ucb-cc-language-optional-software-package-not-installed).  You may find a compiler in `/usr/sfw/bin` or install SolarisStudio downloaded from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/downloads/index.html)

Comment: Thank you fiifim. I have installed SolarisStudio.